# Predicting a continuous-valued attribute with h2o in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, deep-learning, regression, h2o

I have some data that follows an unknown multidimensional nonlinear relationship, for example:

```
x1 <- seq(0, 10, 0.1)
x2 <- seq(5, 15, 0.1)
y1 <- sin(x1)+exp(x2**2)+rnorm(length(x1))
y2 <- log10(abs(x1*x2)+1)+rnorm(length(x1))
```

I want to learn how to transform (x1,x2) into (y1,y2).

How can I use the package `h2o` in R to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

H2O (and most machine learning packages) do not support more than one response variable.  In the case above, you have two response variables, `y1` and `y2`.